# Supertype of std::plus and std::minus / how can I use std::plus and std::minus in a single object?

Tags: c++, stl

I was trying to simplify a piece of code by removing redundant code that only differed in `+=` and `-=`. My idea was to use `std::plus` and `std::minus` instead and thus combine the two methods into one.

Minimal code is:

```cpp
#include <functional>
int main()
{
    // true is actually some condition
    std::binary_function<long, long, long> direction = true ? std::plus<long>() : std::minus<long>();  
}
```

The error is

> error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'std::minus' to 'std::plus'

I don't want to convert std::minus to std::plus, I want to convert everything to std::binary_function.

I tried to help the compiler using a static cast

```cpp
std::binary_function<long, long, long> direction = true 
     ? static_cast<std::binary_function<long, long, long>>(std::plus<long>()) 
     : std::minus<long>();
```

which gives me

> error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'std::plus' to 'std::binary_function<long,long,long>'

Long question short: how can I use std::plus and std::minus in a single object?

Using C++14 in Visual Studio, but open for solutions in newer C++ versions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inheritance from `std::binary_function<T, T, T>` [was removed in C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus). Also, `std::binary_function` [changed in C++11 and changes in C++17 again](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function).

You can use `function` instead:

```cpp
std::function<long(long, long)> direction = true
    ? static_cast<std::function<long(long, long)>>(std::plus<long>())
    : std::minus<long>();
```

and you can simplify more by omitting the type at the operations and using `auto`:

```cpp
auto direction = true
    ? static_cast<std::function<long(long, long)>>(std::plus())
    : std::minus();
```